# How to Use CCache with CMake?

Tags: c++, unix, cmake, ccache

I would like to do the following: If CCache is present in PATH, use "ccache g++" for compilation, else use g++. I tried writing a small my-cmake script containing

```
    CC="ccache gcc" CXX="ccache g++" cmake $*
```

but it does not seem to work (running make still does not use ccache; I checked this using CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on).

**Update:**

As per [this link](http://www.sand-labs.org/owb/wiki/CompilationGuide#Howtospeedupcompilationwithccache) I tried changing my script to

```
     cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="ccache" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ARG1="g++" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="ccache" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ARG1="gcc" $*
```

but cmake bails out complaining that a test failed on using the compiler ccache (which can be expected).

Comment: Why don't you just symlink gcc to ccache? And if you're distributing this, I'd think that the user himself would have done the symlink if he had ccache installed and wanted it to be used..

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I personally have `/usr/lib/ccache` in my `$PATH`. This directory contains loads of symlinks for every possible name the compiler could be called from (like `gcc` and `gcc-4.3`), all pointing to ccache.

And I didn't even create the symlinks. That directory comes pre-filled when I install ccache on Debian.

Comment: Note that this ccache path has to be placed *before* the path where your real compiler is in `$PATH` for it to work. Something like `export PATH = /usr/lib/ccache:$PATH`

Comment: @Gui13: Better than updating the PATH would be to tell cmake explicitly where the gcc it should use is, e.g. cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/lib/ccache/bin/g++

Comment: After `brew install ccache`, I have `/usr/local/Cellar/ccache/3.2.1/libexec/`.

Answer (score 175):

As of CMake 3.4 you can do:

```bash
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache
```

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html

As of CMake 3.17 you can also use the env variable:

```bash
export CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache
cmake -S ... -B ...
```

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html

Comment: And `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache`. These work beautifully! I do not know why **cmake** insists on finding `clang` from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc` (so the symlink trick does not work), rather than from `$PATH`, but your answer works anyway.

Comment: This should be the best answer. No more messing with path variable and compiler symlinks!

Comment: I tried this, but it just gives me the error "ccache: error: Recursive invocation (the name of the ccache binary must be "ccache")".  Looking at the verbose trace, it is trying to run "/usr/local/bin/ccache ccache /usr/bin/c++"...

Comment: How does it interact with RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE?

Comment: This one is the one always work; it works even if you are using a toolchain file and it specifies full path to the compiler (in which modifying system PATH doesn't help). Thanks!

Comment: This answer is very unclear. Where do you use this? in the configuration or the build stage? It's not the build stage, because -D isn't a valid option while building. The answer needs to add a full command at least.

Comment: @ThuongVo anyone who is familiar with cmake knows that -D is a prefix for an option passsed as a CLI parameter. So, given the context of the question, it is somewhat clear to use this when invoking cmake (on configuration that is)

Comment: Is this also supported with the Visual Studio Generator?

Comment: @ThuongVo yes, it should be used during the configuration step. It fails during the build step (I checked that), thanks for your question (I had the same). To Segey: I'm not familiar with `cmake` and don't want/need that; I just use it to compile another project.

Answer (score 120):

It is now possible to specify ccache as a launcher for compile commands and link commands (since cmake 2.8.0). That works for Makefile and Ninja generator. To do this, just set the following properties :

```
find_program(CCACHE_FOUND ccache)
if(CCACHE_FOUND)
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE ccache)
endif()
```

It is also possible to set these properties only for specific directories or targets.

For Ninja, this is possible since version 3.4.
For XCode, Craig Scott gives a workaround in his answer.

It's possible to use ccache for linking too:

```
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_LINK ccache)
```

However, @Emilio Cobos recommends against this as ccache doesn't improve linking speed and can mess with other types of cache like sccache.

Edit : Thanks to uprego and Lekensteyn's comment, I edited the answer to check if ccache is available before using it as launcher and for which generators is it possible to use a compile launcher.

Comment: Many sites implicitly advice using doublequotes like in `find_program(CCACHE_FOUND "ccache")`, I don't know which one is more portable, my mileage did perfectly fine without the need for the doublequotes.

Comment: It's worth noting that this currently only works for Makefile generators (as of cmake 3.3.2). See the manual page of `cmake-properties`.

Comment: It is worth noting that this conflicts with the CTEST_USE_LAUNCHERS setting. Those properties are set here too: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CTestUseLaunchers.cmake#L66-L67

Comment: I think you may want to change the code to [this one](https://invent.kde.org/kde/konsole/merge_requests/26/diffs) *(except, [remove text from inside of `endif()`](https://invent.kde.org/kde/konsole/commit/bccb702d962c2de0aa9806fc38743d2522fa98be))*. The improvements are: 1. There's a configuration option to disable it, and 2. Turns out, colors disappear from GCC/Clang in Make backend when used this way. The `ninja` backend works around it by adding `-fdiagnostics-color` option, so it's advisable to do so for `make` backend too.

Comment: From the docs:
This property is intended for internal use by `ctest(1)`. Projects and developers should use the `<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` target properties or the associated `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` variables instead.

Comment: Also `if (${CCACHE_FOUND})` doesn't work (at least for CMake 3.22). Instead, use `if (${CCACHE_FOUND}-NOTFOUND)`

Answer (score 11):

From CMake 3.1, it is possible to use ccache with the Xcode generator and Ninja is supported from CMake 3.4 onwards. Ninja will honour `RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE` just like the Unix Makefiles generator (so @Babcool's answer gets you there for Ninja too), but getting ccache working for the Xcode generator takes a little more work. The following article explains the method in detail, focussing on a general implementation which works for all three CMake generators and making no assumptions about setting up ccache symlinks or the underlying compiler used (it still lets CMake decide the compiler):

https://crascit.com/2016/04/09/using-ccache-with-cmake/

The general gist of the article is as follows. The start of your `CMakeLists.txt` file should be set up something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_program(CCACHE_PROGRAM ccache)
if(CCACHE_PROGRAM)
    # Support Unix Makefiles and Ninja
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CCACHE_PROGRAM}")
endif()

project(SomeProject)

get_property(RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE)
if(RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE AND CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL "Xcode")
    # Set up wrapper scripts
    configure_file(launch-c.in   launch-c)
    configure_file(launch-cxx.in launch-cxx)
    execute_process(COMMAND chmod a+rx
                            "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/launch-c"
                            "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/launch-cxx")

    # Set Xcode project attributes to route compilation through our scripts
    set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CC         "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/launch-c")
    set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CXX        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/launch-cxx")
    set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD         "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/launch-c")
    set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LDPLUSPLUS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/launch-cxx")
endif()
```

The two script template files `launch-c.in` and `launch-cxx.in` look like this (they should be in the same directory as the `CMakeLists.txt` file):

*launch-c.in:*

```
#!/bin/sh
export CCACHE_CPP2=true
exec "${RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE}" "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" "$@"
```

*launch-cxx.in:*

```
#!/bin/sh
export CCACHE_CPP2=true
exec "${RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE}" "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" "$@"
```

The above uses `RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE` alone for Unix Makefiles and Ninja, but for the Xcode generator it relies on help from CMake's `CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_...` variables support. The setting of the `CC` and `CXX` user-defined Xcode attributes to control the compiler command and `LD` and `LDPLUSPLUS` for the linker command is not, as far as I can tell, a documented feature of Xcode projects, but it does seem to work. If anyone can confirm it is officially supported by Apple, I'll update the linked article and this answer accordingly.

Comment: I also needed the `set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD         "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LDPLUSPLUS "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")` from the mentioned article.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I've updated the answer to include setting LD and LDPLUSPLUS.

Comment: ccache does not support VS compilers, so you can't use it for that. There is a project called [clcache](https://github.com/frerich/clcache) which aims to provide the same functionality for VS, but I can't comment on how well it works.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't like to set a symlink from `g++` to `ccache`. And `CXX="ccache g++"` didn't work for me as some cmake test case wanted to have just the compiler program without attributes.

So I used a small bash script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
ccache g++ "$@"
```

and saved it as an executable in `/usr/bin/ccache-g++`.

Then C configured cmake to use `/usr/bin/ccache-g++` as C++ compiler.
This way it passes the cmake test cases and I feel more comfortable than having symlinks that I might forget about in 2 or 3 weeks and then maybe wonder if something doesn't work...

Answer (score 5):

I verified the following works (source: [this link](http://markmail.org/message/kzgn3qfwlhun5es7#query:ccache%20with%20cmake+page:1+mid:pex5grnqtngxcdpl+state:results)):

```
        CC="gcc" CXX="g++" cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="ccache" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ARG1="g++" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="ccache" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ARG1="gcc" $*
```

**Update**: I later realized that even this does not work. Strangely it works every alternate time (the other times cmake complains).

Answer (score 5):

Let me add one important item that was not mentioned here before.

While bootstrapping a minimalistic build system from the ubuntu:18.04 docker image, I've found that order of installation makes a difference.

In my case ccache worked fine when calling `gcc`, but failed to catch invocations of the same compiler by the other names: `cc` and `c++`.
To fully install ccache, you need to make sure all compilers are installed first, **or** add a call to update-ccache symlinks to be safe.

````
sudo /usr/sbin/update-ccache-symlinks
export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache/:$PATH"```

... and then (due to updated symlinks) also calls to cc and c++ get caught!
````

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about `update-ccache-symlinks`, I was creating `c++` link with a script for a project and it was working but not for another project (still don't know why, the link was fine), `update-ccache-symlinks` solved.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the best way is to symlink gcc,g++ to ccache, but if you would like to use within cmake, try this:

```
export CC="ccache gcc" CXX="ccache g++" cmake ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are 2 methods I think are clean/robust, and also **don't** pollute your CMake code.

1.) Set environment variables

This method is nice since you don't have to individually set it up for each CMake project. The con is you may not want ccache for each CMake project.

```
# Requires CMake 3.17 (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html)
export CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=/usr/bin/ccache
export CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=/usr/bin/ccache
```

2.) Pass in cache variables during project configuration

Con a bit annoying to do for each project. This can be negated by your IDE though.

```
# Requires CMake 3.4
$ cmake ... -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=/usr/bin/ccache \
  -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=/usr/bin/ccache
```

#### NOTE: It isn't really necessary to specify the full path.

If `ccache` is in your path you can just specify `ccache` instead.

```
export CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache
export CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache
```

EDIT:

Note. Sometimes your CMake project will consume non-CMake projects. In that case you may need configure your `PATH` as suggested in Nicolás [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1954144/19739129) in order to cache everything.

Answer (score -1):

It is extending @Nicolas [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1954144/2656799).

Add following line to your `cmake` file:

```
list(PREPEND CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH /usr/lib/ccache)
```

Or add it as argument to `cmake` configuration step:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH=/usr/lib/ccache
```