# Using compiler prefix command(s) with CMake (distcc, ccache)

Tags: c++, c, build, cmake

There are utilities which use an existing compiler by adding a command as a prefix (so instead of calling `cc -c file.c` you could call `distcc cc -c file.c`).

When using CMake the compiler command can be changed, however I ran into problems trying to use `distcc`, though this would likely apply to any command prefix to the compiler (`ccache` too).

- CMake expects the compiler to be an absolute path,
  so setting `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` to `/usr/bin/distcc /usr/bin/cc`, gives an error:

  `/usr/bin/distcc /usr/bin/cc
  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.`
- Setting the compiler to `/usr/bin/distcc` and
  `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ARG1` or `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` to begin with `/usr/bin/cc` works in some cases, but fails with `CHECK_C_SOURCE_COMPILES`
  *(checked if there was some way to support this, even prefixing `CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS` didn't work)*.

---

The only way I found to do this is to wrap the commands in a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/distcc /usr/bin/cc "$@"
```

While this works, It would be nice to be able to use compiler helpers with CMake, without having to go though shell scripts (giving some small overhead when the build system could just use a command prefix).

---

So my question is:

Can CMake use compiler prefix commands (such as distcc) directly?, without shell script wrappers?

Comment: Is setting your `CC`/`CXX` environment variables when calling cmake (e.g. `CC="distcc gcc" cmake ..`) insufficient for some reason?

Comment: @Iskar Jarak, This works! (so I guess this can be the answer).

 Interestingly, internally its using `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` for the first command and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ARG1` for the second. I'm not sure whats going on - because I tried setting these in cmake-gui already and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ARG1` was being ignored with `CHECK_C_SOURCE_COMPILES`.

Comment: Glad it works. Setting the environment variable probably sets some other things as well, things that `CHECK_C_SOURCE_COMPILES` use... although I'm not 100% what... which is why messing with individual variables in CMake is such a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since [CMake 3.4.0](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/release/3.4.html) there has been a [CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_COMPILER_LAUNCHER) variable and corresponding target property [<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html#prop_tgt:%3CLANG%3E_COMPILER_LAUNCHER). So if your project is C-only  you would do something like:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache /path/to/source
CCACHE_PREFIX=distcc make -j`distcc -j`
```

If you have a C++ project, use `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache`.

Or, make your `CMakeLists.txt` smart and use ccache automatically if it can be found:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Enable ccache if not already enabled by symlink masquerading and if no other
# CMake compiler launchers are already defined
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
find_program(CCACHE_EXECUTABLE ccache)
mark_as_advanced(CCACHE_EXECUTABLE)
if(CCACHE_EXECUTABLE)
  foreach(LANG C CXX)
    if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_${LANG}_COMPILER_LAUNCHER AND NOT CMAKE_${LANG}_COMPILER MATCHES ".*/ccache")
      message(STATUS "Enabling ccache for ${LANG}")
      set(CMAKE_${LANG}_COMPILER_LAUNCHER ${CCACHE_EXECUTABLE} CACHE STRING "")
    endif()
  endforeach()
endif()
```

Comment: According to the CMake docs, the `<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` target property will only be honoured by the Makefiles and Ninja generators. You have to do more work to get Xcode to use the launcher. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36515503/1938798) for a more general method which uses the older RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE variable and CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_..., but has similarities to your approach.

Comment: Sadly, CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER is ignored in CHECK_<LANG>_SOURCE_COMPILES, even with the latest cmake (3.10.1). That means the wrapper is still needed if the test result depends on the launcher.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a hint: never use `<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` to cross compile. If `<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` is used together with distcc the absolute compiler path is sent to distcc and the host is not using the cross comping toolchain!

Instead you should use the old school method, just overwrite the compiler path:

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/distcc:$PATH
```

It took me hours to find out...

Comment: For distcc yes, because it isn't running on the same machine. For ccache it still works fine.