# Why does CMake ignore exported CXX and CC environment variables?

Tags: cmake

I am running a CMake (3.4.3) like this as explained in the [CMake FAQ's](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F):

```
export CC="cc_args.py $PWD/../bin/gcc"
export CXX="cc_args.py $PWD/../bin/g++"
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

However when I print `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` it still points to the system's default compilers in `/usr/bin`. It only works when I explicitly read-in the environment variables like this:

```
IF (NOT $ENV{CC} STREQUAL "")
  SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER $ENV{CC})
ENDIF ()
IF (NOT $ENV{CXX} STREQUAL "")
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER $ENV{CXX})
ENDIF ()
```

But even then the building fails with this message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/peterg/bin/cc_args.py /home/peterg/Code/build/../bin/g++: not found
```

However I am certain that all paths are correct since executing just the path between the two colons outputs this as expected:

```
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

#### Update:

It seems the compiling process does not like spaces in the compiler paths. I've now created two scripts (one for GCC and one for CC) which wrap the commands and propagate the arguments and that seems to work. But it still seems I am doing something fundamentally wrong because CMake would also not accept the exported `CC=proxy_script_cc.sh` and `GCC=proxy_script_gcc.sh` variables without spaces by itself.

Comment: Just use `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and don't mess around with shell variables.

Comment: I think what you are searching for is something like `set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "bash proxy_script_cc.sh")` or global variables [`CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html)

Comment: @Florian The `cc_args.py` script wraps the compiler to extract information for auto-completion.

Comment: For me, CMake ignores `ENV{CC}` on Windows but not CentOS. In both cases there are no spaces in the path to GCC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

**Problem**

I've given you code a try and could reproduce your problem

```
CMake Error at [...]/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:56 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CXX:

  cc_args.py [... PWD ...]/../bin/g++.
```

If I look at [`CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake#L50) code and at [`get_filename_component()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_filename_component.html) documentation, it just means that it didn't find `cc_args.py` in "the system search path" or relative to your binary output directory.

**Solution**

So it does work when you give a full path or a relative path to your binary output dir with something like

```
export CC="../cc_args.py ../bin/gcc"
export CXX="../cc_args.py ../bin/g++"
```

**Alternative**

CMake does allow to define "launcher scripts" e.g. with [`CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html)

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug 
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=../cc_args.py 
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=../cc_args.py 
        ..
```

**References**

- [How to Use CCache with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815688/how-to-use-ccache-with-cmake)
- [Save and reprint warnings for successfully-compiled files on subsequent builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348508/save-and-reprint-warnings-for-successfully-compiled-files-on-subsequent-builds)

Answer (score 4):

Pass `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=<path/to/compiler>` to your CMake call. That's less error prone compared to fiddling with shell variables.

Comment: What exactly does that flag do?

Comment: Via this flag you can tell the path to the C++ compiler CMake is supposed to use.