# Is there a way to avoid recompile all opencv?

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to make opencv (3.1.0) as I want, changing some parameters in the cmake command line to change the modules that I want to use.

The problem is that everytime that I touch cmake all the source is rebuilt, with a high time consume.

Is there a way to change, for example with_gtk, and don't waste hour+?

(platform ubuntu-linux 16.10)

Comment: your mileage may vary, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815688/how-to-use-ccache-with-cmake

Comment: libopencv 3.1 is packaged on Debian/Sid. Are you sure you don't have it on your Ubuntu? Did you try `apt-get install libopencv-dev libopencv-core3.1` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sadly there is no 3.x on ubuntu.

Comment: @Lanting sound complex, but I will check.

Comment: I doubt that CMake will ever deduce whether a changed flag requires recompiling targets or not. A tip to speed up the build process: Try Ninja instead of Make as the build tool.

Comment: Try `make -j 8` or similar to build in parallel.

Comment: @MarkSetchell actually I did with j=10 (I have 12cores) and it takes arround 50 minutes, I thinking in remove cuda support until I get an stable compilation.